# How to properly register subdomains

Tags: dns, vps, domain-name, subdomain

tl;dr: What's the proper way to make a domain point to an IP and a subdomain point to another? Any additional records required besides two `A` records?

---

I'm working on an e-commerce that used to live in a VPS as a huge WordPress site. Nowadays, the e-commerce lives in some other platform, and the VPS is sitting there with its old WordPress site and nothing pointing to it.

The domain registrar contains two records that point to this new platform: an `A` record of `example.com` that points to its IP and a `CNAME` record of `www.example.com` that points to a specific address of the platform.

I was tasked with something simple: create a subdomain `blog.example.com` and point that to the VPS, so that `blog.example.com` would show the WordPress site that lives there. That's exactly what I did: created an `A` record of `blog.example.com` that points to the VPS's IP address.

My problem is: when I created this new record, it seemed like the internet became confused. The new `blog.example.com` address started redirecting to `example.com` (i.e. trying to render `example.com/login` if you typed `blog.example.com/login`). Also, typing `example.com` directly would not work, only `www.example.com`. I had basically shut down `example.com` with this new `A` record.

I removed the `A` record and started searching the internet to understand what had happened, but couldn't quite come across anything that justifies this behaviour. Based on multiple articles and questions I've read, my best guesses are:

- This is something related to the `example.com` SSL certificate that still lives in the VPS so pointing to it from any address might cause unexpected redirects.
- An additional `CNAME` record of `www.blog.example.com` that points to `blog.example.com` would be required for this to work.

Haven't tested any of these yet, as the e-commerce might go down once again if I do. Regardless, I would much appreciate any insights on how to properly pull this off.

Comment: Did the URL shown in the browser automatically change from blog.example.com to example.com, or did it just return the pages while still staying at blog.example.com? What do you mean by "stopped working", did the www subdomain stop resolving through DNS or did the server start returning the wrong pages?

Comment: - The URL changed automatically from `blog.example.com` to `example.com`.

- When I said that `example.com` stopped working, I meant it started to try rendering pages only the `blog` webserver should render. If you typed purposefully `example.com`, it would redirect to `/foo`, which is a redirect `blog` makes internally.  `www.example.com`, on the other hand, was not affected by this confusion, it was pointing to where `example.com` should.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 elements at play here.

1. From a DNS POV using an A record is correct and all that is required. For http(s) all the DNS is used for is finding the IP address (and optionally, but not commonly used to validate an ssl cert)
2. The web server. This is where you are running in to issues. Practically speaking  the web server needs to know the domain name.  Depending on how its set up, and how the application is set up it will be doing redirects. **this is what is happening - and where you want to focus your energy**
3. The SSL cert needs to match the domain name.  If you are not getting cert/security errors in your browser, this is probably OK.

Comment: The SSL certs might in fact be the issue here. I'm conducting some tests on this, and will be back with results still today. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: +1. Also, the website is probably redirecting because of its configuration. Also, may want to fix your tyops. ;)

Comment: Wordpress includes a "site url" setting (and if you land at a wordpress site using a different domain name it will redirect you) - it sounds like this is ypur problem. https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/ has methods you can use to fix this.

Comment: The SSL certs are not this issue.  The issue is the webserver or webapp redirecting the browser, or the browser caching a redirect that no longer exists.  @davidgo's answer is correct and the SSL cert note he made is a bonus but secondary & likley a distration to your problem, which redirecting.  Once that is fixed deal with SSL.  Server manages redirect, browser might cache it.  Any website/VPS  mgmt tools as well as things like  global .htaccess files.  Also a great suspect is Wordpress itself as it performs tons of redirecting out of the box and any add-ons.  Just keeping you focused.

Comment: dang @davidgo that was my pearl :-)  Yours is better with URL and beat mine.   I still had to list all the other suspects :-(